# Unicode Error Ascii art

Tags: python

estoy haciendo una terminal para mi propio sistema  operativo y eso
Al hacer ascii art en la consola
Este ascii art:

```
█▀ ▄▀█ █▀▄ █▀█ █▀█   █▀ █▀▀ ▀█▀ █ █ █▀█
▄█ █▀█ █▄▀ █▀▄ █▄█   ▄█ ██▄  █  █▄█ █▀▀
```

Pero al momento de poner

```
print(image1)#Image1 es el ascii art mencionado anteriormente
```

sucede un error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "h:\bind.d\apps\enproceso\game_peter\os\main.py", line 8, in 
> print(image1)
> File "C:\Users\Maxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-20: character maps to

Y al momento de poner

```
print(image1.enconde("utf-8))
```

Sale, pero en codigo binario

> \n\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83 \xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\n\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83 \xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x80\n

Para probar si era automaticamente generado por python o era el del ascii art, lo escribi en un archivo

```
with open("a.txt","wb") as f:
    f.write(b'\n\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83 \xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\n\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83 \xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x80\n')
```

Efectivamente. Salió el mismo ascii art escrito en el archivo pero en caracteres, no en binario
adjunto el codigo completo

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time
import os
imgbin=b'\n\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83 \xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\n\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83 \xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x91\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x84\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x80\x83\xe2\x96\x88\xe2\x96\x80\xe2\x96\x80\n'#Codigo binario que decidi guardar por las dudas
image1="""
█▀ ▄▀█ █▀▄ █▀█ █▀█   █▀ █▀▀ ▀█▀ █ █ █▀█
▄█ █▀█ █▄▀ █▀▄ █▄█   ▄█ ██▄  █  █▄█ █▀▀
"""#Ascii art
print(image1)#Lo imprimo
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "h:\bind.d\apps\enproceso\game_peter\os\main.py", line 9, in 
> print(image1)
> File "C:\Users\Maxi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-20: character maps to

Comment: Pues yo acabo de declarar tu ascii art como `image = """<tu ascii chart>"""` y luego le he dado `print(image)` y [lo veo sin problemas](https://ibb.co/T1njh3z) en la consola. No es posible reproducir tu error. Supongo que sea cosa que solo pase en windows.

Comment: A mi me sucede lo mismo que Jaime. Podrías agregar un [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) donde ocurra ese error por favor? Como obtienes el texto? Está dentro del script? Lo lees de un archivo de texto?

Comment: Por cierto, @JaimeMenéndez yo tengo windows.

Comment: @DanteS. genial!. Tu lo probaste en windows y yo en linux, y el usuario por lo que muestra su `Traceback` usa windows, por lo tanto, como bien dices, es un problema que no puede reproducirse. Esperemos que, si requiere ayuda, adjunte más detalles a su pregunta.

Comment: Ya agregue alguna informacion que podria se r de ayuda

Comment: @fourseven Ahora me perdí ¿Eso no resolvió tu problema o tienes algún otro error? Dices que _"Efectivamente. Salió el mismo ascii art escrito en el archivo pero en caracteres, no en binario"_ ¿No es eso lo que querías? Si es lo que querías por favor, no edites tu pregunta con la respuesta, agrega una respuesta respondiéndote tu mismo.

Comment: Sigue funcionandome bien. Que versión de Python estás usando? Quizá usas una versión antigua (como 2.7) y en ese caso podría tener conflicto con los caracteres unicode.

Comment: No, yo queria imprimirlo en la consola, pero al imprimirlo salia error, y al agregarle `.enconde("utf-8")` salia en binario, yo lo escribi en un archivo para saber si el codigo binario fue generado automaticamente o era el ascii art pero en binario. PD: Uso python 3.8.0

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez esa parte estaba antes de la edición. Se refiere a cuando escribió un archivo con la cadena codificada en utf-8.

Comment: Seguro que no usas una versión antigua? Aunque sea la 3.2? Si no es eso no te puedo ayudar. Pues no puedo reproducir el error y por lo tanto tampoco intentar solucionarlo...

Comment: No, la unica que tengo es la 3.8.0, ninguna mas

Comment: Le hice debug con vscode y me funciono, pero lo corro normal mente y no sirve

Comment: La verdad que no entiendo esto

Comment: @fourseven en tu código prueba `print(imgbin.decode("utf-8"))` con la variable `imgbin` que tienes declarada.

Comment: me sale el mismo error

Comment: Por qué cambiaste el título? Eso hace que la publicación sea más confusa

Comment: Recuerda que si tienes muchos votos negativas, preguntas cerradas o reportadas te pueden bloquear la cuenta.